# I want to post from a react app to an expressjs api

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am learning react and expressjs for fun.  I have a REST api in express and I have all the get methods working with my react app.  Meaning I can call and use the get or get/i and it works.  I am trying to do the post method now and I think im missing some small parts.  I know this code is messy but its just a sandbox

Here is my express post method. It does post and write to mongo hard coded now I am trying to send it a request from react and use those values.  the console.log all say undefined in the log.

request  [object Object]

tony  params [object Object]

Tony Name undefined

Tony Path /api/courses

```
    //const tony = validateCourse(req.body);
    const tony = req;
    console.log("request  " + tony);
    console.log("tony  params " + tony.params);
    console.log("Tony Name " + tony.name);
    console.log("Tony Path " + tony.path);

    // this posts with hard coded values need to get values from the react post now
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', function (err, client) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var db = client.db('tc-fant-maps');
        db.collection('mapss').insertOne({name: 'Map020', description: 'This is the map of test', path:'http://d9amq8b4jzm6k.cloudfront.net/elrue001.png'}, function (findErr, result) {
            if (findErr) throw findErr;
            //console.log(result);
            client.close();
            res.send(result);
        });
    });
```

Here is my react code that does hit the api as the hard coded values actually show up in mongo. Meaning it hits my post and my hardcoded method executes.  I just dont see the new values im passing in the console.log

````
function CreateMap() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [description, setDescription] = useState('')
  const [path, setPath] = useState('')
  const submit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch(`http://localhost:3001/api/courses`, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({ name, description, path }),
    })
    console.log("tony yimt")
  }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={submit}>
      <label htmlFor="name">Map Name</label>
      <input
        name="name"
        value={name}
        onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
        />
      <br />
      <label htmlFor="description">EMap Description</label>
      <input
        type="description"
        name="description"
        value={description}
        onChange={e => setDescription(e.target.value)}
       />
      <br />
      <label htmlFor="path">Map Image Path</label>
      <input
        type="path"
        name="path"
        value={path}
        onChange={e => setPath(e.target.value)}
       />
       <br />
      <button type="submit">Send it!</button>
    </form>
  )
}

export default CreateMap ```

When I look at the post in chrome I see

request payload 

{"name":"fran","description":"k","path":"foj"}

which is what I entered on my web form (just typed in junk) and I get a status 200 back. 

I either do not know how to get the body from the request and use it in express or I am sending the payload wrong from react.  

sorry for the mess as I said its a sandbox but it does send a payload.

so short story is im trying to replace the hard coded 

({name: 'Map020', description: 'This is the map of test', path:'http://d9amq8b4jzm6k.cloudfront.net/elrue001.png'}

with the values in my react form post
````

Comment: Have you configured body parser ?

Comment: The error you mentioned in Augustus's answer would be resolved by the answer I gave. Please see answer. You're trying to access the body params directly from the req object, rather than the req.body

Answer (score 0):

Your fetch call, and api need to be modified a bit. Your fetch should look more like this:

```
fetch(`http://localhost:3001/api/courses`, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({ name: name, 
                         description: description, 
                         path: path }),
 })
```

Notice that I added the property names, then set their values.

And your api needs to access the body object of the request:

```
const tony = req;
console.log("request  " + tony);
console.log("tony  params " + tony.body.params);
console.log("Tony Name " + tony.body.name);
console.log("Tony Path " + tony.body.path);
```

Notice the body property being accessed within the request object.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have the body parser package, you should get it and add it to your app

```js
var app = express();
app.use(bodyparser.json());
```

Then you can get the json body

```js
npm install body-parser
```

Comment: with those changes I still get this in my express side -- request  [object Object]
tony  params undefined
Tony Name undefined
Tony Path undefined

Comment: One more update all those console.logs work fine if I send a postman request with the same params so my react is not sending something in the format it expects?

Comment: @ducati1212 Please see my answer... It resolves the very problem your expressing.

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out to be a 'cors' issue.  I had no cors set on the react app and my limited experience with it just assumed everything running on local host was ok and the error was not clear to me.

app.use(cors({
origin: 'http://localhost:3002'
}));

Once I added this to express side and enabled cors on react it worked.

That is 6 hours of my life I wont get back but good to have worked through it.